# Equalize Two Separate Table Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an equalize table function

```
($controlTable, $referenceTable) {
  $referenceTable.find('tr').each(function (index) {
    var refRow = $(this)
    var controlRow = $controlTable.find('tr:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')');

    var refRowHeight = refRow.height();
    var controlRowHeight = controlRow.height();

    if (refRowHeight > controlRowHeight) {
      controlRow.height(refRowHeight);
    } else {
      refRow.height(controlRowHeight);
    }
  });
}
```

This function is supposed to go through each table rows and equalize their heights based on the tallest, but for some reason I see a 1px to 3px  difference making some table rows not to align properly, at first I thought it might have to use the outerWidth, but it did not make sense nor did it work after trying it. This happens especially when there is a line break.

PS: I am running this function on page load, and also watching for when page resizes.

Find a codepen below showing this behaviour

https://codepen.io/sslgeorge/pen/EwqMde

Comment: Do all the tables have the css the same?

Comment: @TKoL Yes, the CSS are the same, I even cleared out the CSS that adds padding, but it behaved in the same way

Comment: Well have you tried figuring out specifically which rows are different height and inspecting them in Chrome element inspector?

Comment: @TKoL I did, I have 13 rows, only 4 have these issue, even though the two tables end up with the same height, the alignments of those 4 rows are off

Comment: can you replicate the problem here in a snippet ?

Comment: @MihaiT Okay doing that

Comment: @MihaiT done, https://codepen.io/sslgeorge/pen/EwqMde

Comment: Both tables have height 1359px in recent Chrome. Do they have different heights in your browser? Also, why not just make one table?

Comment: @duhaime because we want the right one to scroll

Comment: Can't you just use some css, like `table td { overflow: auto }` and  `table td:first-of-type {overflow: none};` Do those tables have different heights in your browser? If so, what browser and os are you on?

Comment: I am on Mac OSX, Chrome 62 @duhaime

Comment: Also, they have the same heights, we are not scrolling the tds, we are scrolling the whole table. if you resize the pen you will see the behaviour on the right one